# Removing \r\n from dataframe that came from html table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using python, pandas
I have a dataframe that is created with `pandas.read_html(table)`, with the table being an html table that was scraped off a website. When the table is printed, it has '\r\n' around everything, which I want to remove for readability. When I remove it with `df = pandas.read_html(table.replace(r'\r\n', ''))[0]`, it breaks the table and nothing is outputted. How do I remove '\r\n' without breaking the table?

Edit: here is test code

````
df = pd.DataFrame({r'\r\n Column1\r\n':[r'\r\n Data1\r\n',r'\r\n Data2\r\n',r'\r\n Data3\r\n'],
                   r'\r\n Column2\r\n':[r'\r\n Data4\r\n',r'\r\n Data5\r\n',r'\r\n Data6\r\n']})

print (df)
cols_to_check = [r'\r\n Column1\r\n']
print (df[cols_to_check])
df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].replace({r'\r\n':''}, regex=True)
print(df)```
````

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

> method 1 :

Try this :

```
df.replace({r'\r\n': ''}, regex=True)
```

if the problem still persists try to modify column by column

```
df['column'].replace({r'\r\n': ''}, regex=True)
```

else try to change one cell to debug the problem

```
df.iloc[1,2].replace({r'\r\n': ''}, regex=True)
```

> method 2 :
> install BeautifulSoup `pip install BeautifulSoup` and try this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
df.Column = df.Column.apply(lambda r: BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser').get_text())
```

Comment: Found that in another stackoverflow page but unsuccessful. Column by column is also tricky and hasn't worked so far

Answer (score 0):

Try this, looks like the \ need to be escaped. And the columns need to be renamed, rather than use replace.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({r'\r\n Column1\r\n':[r'\r\n Data1\r\n',r'\r\n Data2\r\n',r'\r\n Data3\r\n'],
                   r'\r\n Column2\r\n':[r'\r\n Data4\r\n',r'\r\n Data5\r\n',r'\r\n Data6\r\n']})


new_cols = []
for c in df.columns.tolist():
    new_cols.append(c.replace('\\r\\n', ''))

    df.columns = new_cols
    
    df.replace({r'\\r\\n': ''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
   Column1  Column2
0    Data1    Data4
1    Data2    Data5
2    Data3    Data6
```

Also notice your columns have a space, so you may want to clean that up as well

```
In [38]: df.columns
Out[38]: Index([' Column1', ' Column2'], dtype='object')
```